# Sample from half a Gaussian distribution

Tags: matlab, statistics, distribution, random, normal-distribution

Suppose `n = N(0,1)` is a normal distribution. In MATLAB, when the `randn(1,1)` function is used, a sample is extracted from `n`.

However, I have a different objective: I would like to sample from the upper (or lower) half distribution, i.e., from the half going from the left tail to the mean (or from the mean to the right tail).

A dummy way of doing this would be:

```
while sample > mean
    sample from gaussian
end
```

However, since I have to extract a lot of samples in my code, this solution would not be appreciated. Is there a smarter way of extracting those samples, without involving a loop?

Answer (score 4):

Given that your Gaussian is symmetrical around zero, you can use

```
sample = randn(n, 1); 
sample(sample < 0) = -sample(sample < 0);
```

Note that this only works if the mean of the Gaussian is zero.

For Gaussians with arbitrary means, you can use:

```
sample(sample < mean(sample)) = -sample(sample < mean(sample)) + 2*mean(sample);
```